# C# an organized way to hide (clean up) many declared variables from my main?

Tags: c#, header-files, variable-declaration, variable-initialization

So if I have a lot of long global string variables in my main that end up taking up a lot of lines in my main (around 500 to give you an idea) is there a way I can hide them somewhere else but still access them in my main? To better clarify, if this was c++ I'd just make a header with these variables defined and then link the header. Can I do the same with c#?

Here's an example of 1 of many parsed string arrays that contribute 500 lines of code to my main:

```
string [] m1756EN2T = @"    MODULE Drives (Description := ""~"",
               Parent := ""Local"",
               ParentModPortId := 1,
               CatalogNumber := ""1756-EN2T"",
               Vendor := 1,
               ProductType := 12,
               ProductCode := 166,
               Major := 10,
               Minor := 1,
               PortLabel := ""RxBACKPLANE"",
               Slot := 5,
               NodeAddress := ""192.168.0.1"",
               Mode := 2#0000_0000_0000_0000,
               CompatibleModule := 1,
               KeyMask := 2#0000_0000_0001_1111)
        ExtendedProp := [[[___<public><ConfigID>131178</ConfigID></public>___]]]
        ConfigData := [20,0,393217,33619969,256,0];
        CONNECTION Input2(Rate := 500000,
                           EventID := 0)

        END_CONNECTION

END_MODULE".Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);`
```

EDIT: Please someone with more experience fix the code snippet, not sure what went wrong

Comment: Do you actually have a lot of variables, or is it really just a lot of text? It sounds like it could be in an embedded resource...

Comment: If you JUST want to hide them, you can use #region {name} and #endregion if you really want them gone, use a file or a separate class.

Comment: @JonSkeet - 'cause it's not a program until it has three public static classes.

Comment: @JonSkeet that sounds interesting. It's about 20 string arrays ranging in different lengths. Is there a better way than to initialize string variables? I thought of embedding a text file and pulling from that but it seems kind of troublesome to navigate through. With my current method I just have to call the array name of the card I want. And it saves formatting and everything for me. The down side is it seems kinda unprofessional...

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger I'd still like to see it but I don't want it hogging up all the space in my main. (not that space is an issue really it jsut seems kinda unprofessional / out of place you know?) but I still need to be able to see this stuff, just I'd prefer it to not be on my main.

Comment: I have some vague idea about using a static class that has properties with names like "m1756EN2T".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to hide, use #region / #endregion

If you want something like C++ `#include` functionality, you can use [partial class feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx): split your class into multiple source files, some with the strings, another with the actual source code.

But IMO better solution  is move the strings from C# source to some other place.
For example, to a string table [in a .resx file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.90).aspx). This way the IDE will give you nice GUI for editing the data, and the built-in code generator will allow you to refer those strings from C# code by their symbolic names.

Comment: do you have any literature on string tables for .resx files?

Comment: Right click on your project, Add, New Item…, Visual C# Items / General / Resource File
Then see this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xhwfctz(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: This is perfect tyvm

Comment: one last thing sorry, how do I access these strings in my resources? Like if I wanted to do something like:

`string mainString = refString`

Comment: After you’ll compile the project, the code generator will create a class from your .resx. It will place the generated code into the {file}.Designer.cs. Inside the generated class, you’ll find a static property for each string in your table. To read the strings, just use those generated properties.

Comment: I added the strings to my project resources and rebuilt the solution but I can't find anything relevant to my strings in Form1.Designer.cs. Do I have to add the strings to my Form1.resx instead of Resources.resx?

Comment: nvm found it. Okay I see them in the designer, how do I access them? This is what I'm supposed to see right?:

`        internal static string m1734AENTR {
            get {
                return ResourceManager.GetString("m1734AENTR", resourceCulture);
            }
        }`

Comment: You can access the value using `{class}.m1734AENTR` anywhere in your C# code. The `{class}` is typically the name of your .resx file.